# Can't update Xcode 5.1 to Xcode 5.1.1 with Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I've made an app for iOS7 using Xcode 5.1 and Yosemite OS. When I tried to submit my app, it showed the following error "This bundle is invalid. new apps and updates submitted to the app store must be built with public"

After searching about that error, I realized I need Xcode 5.1.1 in order to submit my app. So I went to App Store to update my Xcode 5.1 to the new version (5.1.1) and it said I couldn't update my software because I was using a new OS version (Yosemite).

So at this time I'm stuck because I don't want to downgrade to Mavericks and I want to update Xcode 5.1.1 ... is it possible to fix this issue? Or do I have to downgrade to Mavericks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download Xcode 5.1.1 from the [Apple Developer Downloads website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and install it from `.dmg`.